# Pandas CSV KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to get the values of a specific column called "Artikelnummer", but i only get a "KeyError"

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('AB_Statistik.csv', encoding="latin1")

number = df[('Artikelnummer')]
```

Same with:

```
number = df['Artikelnummer']
```

df.head() output:

```
    Stammartikelnummer;Artikelnummer;EAN;Artikel;Verkaufsmenge;Summe VK Netto;Summe VK Brutto;Summe EK;Verkaufserlös;Afterbuy-Shop-Bestand;Auktionsbestand;Lagerreichweite
145458072;1304;0791266404021;Folienballon - 16 ... 06;3.739 06;1.017 22;2.721                                       84;206;0;108
```

Comment: Can you post df.head() ?

Comment: Please post df.columns.values

Comment: If you claim this column is called "number" why are you referencing it with "Artikelnummer"?  `KeyError` means that the column name "Artikelnummer" doesn't exist?

Comment: It seems like the column you want to access does not exist.

Comment: Sorry i changed the value "Number" back to "Artikelnummer"

Comment: include sep = ';', engine = 'python'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from documentation:

*sep : str, default ‘,’*

so you need to set:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('AB_Statistik.csv', encoding="latin1", sep=';')
```